How to Register with an IMS Server in Android?
I am developing an Android application that integrates VoIP services using IMS (IP Multimedia Subsystem). I need to register with an IMS server to authenticate and establish communication sessions. I understand that SIP (Session Initiation Protocol) is used for this purpose, but since SipManager and related classes are deprecated, I’m looking for alternative methods to achieve this.
Details:
Registration: My goal is to register with an IMS server to authenticate users and manage communication sessions.
What I Have Tried:
Using SipManager: I understand that SipManager is deprecated and therefore not suitable for future implementations.
SIP Libraries: I am exploring alternatives such as PJSIP and Jitsi. I am not sure how to implement the registration process with these libraries.
Custom Implementation: I am also considering building a custom SIP stack but need guidance on handling IMS registration.
Challenges:
IMS Registration: How do I correctly handle SIP registration with an IMS server?
Authentication: What is the proper way to authenticate with the IMS server?
Handling Responses: How should I handle SIP responses from the IMS server, such as registration success or failure?
How can I register with an IMS server in an Android application using modern, supported libraries or approaches? What steps should I follow to ensure successful registration, and how do I handle responses from the server?

Try to use Siprix, here is example of the Android app with ability to register multiple accounts and make calls: https://github.com/siprix/SampleJava.
